# 2D arrays that change with user input

Tags: java

I've been asked to make a program that prints a 5x5 grid that allows users to input an integer to determine where an "x" will be put. e.g if the user inputs 1 it would print out.

```
x 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Here's my code. I've built the array but I just can't seem to get it to print out the array where the inputted integer has an effect. Also would I just loop the same code again and again until someone wins or all spaces have been filled.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grade {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int rows = 5;
        final int columns = 5;
        int one;
        int two;

        int[][] grid = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }

        System.out.println("player one choose your position");
        one = input.nextInt();

        while (one > 25 || one < 1) {
            System.out.println("error");
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                input.next();
            }
            one = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("player two choose your position");
        two = input.nextInt();

        while (two > 25 || two < 1) {
            System.out.println("error");
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                input.next();
            }
            two = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("" + one);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, for one, you have no code, at all, that actually updates the array with your `one` and `two` values...

Comment: I tried to do System.out.print(grid[one][j] + " "); but it didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: which would also not work. you have a 5x5 array, and are prompting the user for 1->25. if they choose 25, you're doing `grid[25][j]` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Right okay, so I'm going about this all wrong. What's the best way to actually have the array updated with the one and two values? Thanks

Comment: Your data collection is of type `int[][]`. You will never be able to update an index with `X` since this collection only holds `int`. I would actually suggest using a 1-D `String` array. But just print it like a 2-D grid. Using a 1-D array is pretty easy to update with user input. `stringArray[userInput] = "x"`. You won't have to worry about mapping user input (just one number) to 2 numbers (row and column)

Comment: you'd need to convert the user input into grid coordinates, e.g. `6 -> (2,1)` and then `grid[2][1] = 'x'` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need to do what you are asking is posted below. Since `x` is an `int` in your code you needed an algorithm to make it so that you could set the location properly in the `int[][]`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeSO
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in);

    int remainder;
    int down;
    int column;
    int row;

    int rows = 5;
    int columns = 5;
    int one;
    int two;

    int[][] grid;

    public void makeLocation(int x, int r, int c)
    {
        remainder = x % c;
        down = (int) x / r;

        if(x % c!=0)
        {
            column = remainder-1;
        }
        else
        {
            column = remainder;
        }

        if(x % c==0)
        {
            row=down-1;
            column = remainder+4;
        }
        else
        {
            row=down;
        }
    }

    public void makeArray()
    {
        grid = new int[rows][columns];

        System.out.println("Player 1: Please chose a number between 1 and 25");
        one = input.nextInt();

        while (one > 25 || one < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Number");
            System.out.println("Player 1: Please enter a number between 1 and 25");
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                input.next();
            }
            one = input.nextInt();
        }

        makeLocation(one,columns,rows);
        grid[row][column]= 1;

        System.out.println("Player 2: Please chose a number between 1 and 25");
        two = input.nextInt();

        while (two > 25 || two < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Number");
            System.out.println("Player 2: Please enter a number between 1 and 25");
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                input.next();
            }
            two = input.nextInt();
        }

        makeLocation(two,columns,rows);
        grid[row][column]= 2;
    }

    public void displayArray()
    {
        for (int[] smallGrid: grid) 
        {
            for (int elem: smallGrid) 
            {
                System.out.print(elem);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GradeSO gSO = new GradeSO();
        gSO.makeArray();
        gSO.displayArray();
    }
}
```